# Doctrine - Missing value for primary key

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, primary-key

I have this entity:

```
/**
 * Class ParserURLs
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ParserURLsRepository")
 */
class ParserURLs
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
 */
protected $external_id;

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Parser")
 */
protected $parser;

...
}
```

Any I try to get results filtering by $parser, like this:

```
$query = $this->doctrine->getManager()->createQuery(
            'SELECT u
            FROM AppBundle:ParserURLs u
            WHERE u.parser = :parser')
->setParameter('parser', $this->parser);

$result = $query->getResult();
```

But Doctrine tell me: `Missing value for primary key parser on AppBundle\Entity\ParserURLs`

I think that the problem es because the multiple primary key **external_id-parser** but now, I only want search by one of their. It's not possible in Doctrine? I need this primary keys.
Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing name property in your annotations. Your definition should look like this:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string", length=9)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $id;
```

Where name="id" is your name of the field from you DB

If your ID has autoincrement you have to add this line:

```
@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
```